# alias a multipart command on the lefthand side in bash

Tags: bash, command, alias

I have a command (in Linux Bash) that I want to prevent myself from ever running with a specific option. However, I want to still run that command with other options. So for example the following are OK:

```
command opt1
command opt2
```

But I want to disable

```
command badopt
```

I was thinking of doing this by aliasing it to a nonexistant command in my profile, like

```
alias "command badopt"=djskagldjkgldasg
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any other suggestions for (easily) disabling my ability to use this specific option while preserving my ability to use other options?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat >> $HOME/.bashrc
shutdown () {
  if [ "x$1" = x-h ]; then
    echo Please do not run shutdown with the -h option.
    return
  fi
  /sbin/shutdown "$@"
}
```

*# updated*

Comment: Thank you, this is a cool idea. However, when I try to do this, it actually immediately terminates my Bash session, like it is exiting out. This happens whether I use the "good" option or the "bad" option, and even if I get rid of the exit 1 line.

Comment: Oh right, that's a bug. I was about to test it when I got a phone call. Just change: `exit 1` to `return` and get rid of the `exec`

Comment: Wouldn't `return 1` be more useful here?

Answer (score 0):

bash functions are what you want. Assuming the command you want to intercept is named "foo":

```
foo () {
    case "$1" in 
        badopt) 
            echo "do not push this button again" >&2
            return 1
            ;;
    esac
    command foo "$@"
}
```

The keyword `command` is used to prevent the function from calling itself recursively.